# Firebase project Creating Issue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I want to create a Firebase project in the same Google Console Project means I want to use all APIs from a single GCP but while creating Project it's showing

> The operation has failed (Reason: Billing Account
> [---------------/---------------------] cannot pay for
> businessEntity/CLOUD_PLATFORM)

please someone can explain this issue?

Comment: what do you mean "create Firebase project **in** GCP project"? its not possible to create project hierarchy... could you please add more details? What kind of project is it? I think you can use the same project in Firebase like in GCP...

Comment: Do you have any other billing account? If you have created a new account and if it has $300 free trial credits and you can use it for a Firebase project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of the selection of billing accounts. Some of the APIs do not work with INR fiat, and by two separate accounts that support two different currencies(INR and USD). To resolve this kind of error, please look into your billing accounts.